# How to make clickable Flash Video or open a url by click on flash video in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, flash

I have flash object(video). And i want to open a page while on click on it. I have done it by taking it inside a div and on click of div i open the page. But its not working in chrome and IE. Its working fine in Firefox. My code is as below:

```
<div class="HouseImage" onclick="window.open('Contact','_self')" style="height: 300px;
                overflow: hidden;">
                <object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="351"
                    height="332">
                    <param name="movie" value="Flash/Banner.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                    <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
                    <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
                    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
                    <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
                    <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Flash/Banner.swf" width="351"
                        height="332">
                        <!--<![endif]-->
                        <param name="quality" value="high" />
                        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                        <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
                        <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
                        <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
                        <div>
                            <h4>
                                Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
                            <p>
                                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif"
                                        alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    </object>
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                </object>
            </div>
```

Please help me as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to open link via flash. If you don't have access to code you could write "special" flash loader, which would load Flash/Banner.swf inside itself, and have onclick event to load page.

You can also try putting transparent div or gif above flash animation, but it's a mess involving absolute positioning and it probably doesn't work on all browsers.